# How can a object detect the mouse in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision

```
import pygame
from pygame.constants import( QUIT, KEYDOWN, KEYUP, K_LEFT, K_RIGHT, K_ESCAPE, K_SPACE, 
MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
import os
from random import randint


class Settings:
  w_width = 800
  w_height = 600
  w_border = 50
  file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
  image_path = os.path.join(file_path, "pictures")




class Background(object):
  def __init__(self, filename):
     self.imageo = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(Settings.image_path, filename))
     self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.imageo, (Settings.w_width, Settings.w_height)).convert()
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

  def draw(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

I have here the bubbles class and i want to do it that when you click a bubble it despawns but i dont know how the bubbles detect the mouse cursor and how the bubbles despawn.
I already tried to add the mouse position function but I dont know hot to use it.
And I searched on the Internet but I found nothing about that.

```
class Bubble(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.width = 50
    self.height = 300
    self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(Settings.image_path, "Blase.png ")).convert_alpha()
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (25, 25))
    self.rect_br = (Settings.w_width//2) + 100, (Settings.w_height//2) + 100
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.mousex, self.mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    self.cx = self.width - 25
    self.cy = self.height - 25
    self.rect.left = randint(Settings.w_border, Settings.w_width - Settings.w_border)
    self.rect.top = randint(Settings.w_border, Settings.w_height - (Settings.w_border * 2))


  def update(self):
    pass

  def scale_up(self):
    self.scale["width"] += 2
    self.scale["height"] += 2

 def scale_down(self):
    self.scale["width"] -= 2
    self.scale["height"] -= 2

 def events(self):
    pass

 def draw(self, screen):
    screen.blit(self.image,self.rect )
```

Here is where everythings run from the code

```
class Game(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((Settings.w_width, Settings.w_height))
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.runn = False
    self.background = Background("Hintergrund.png")
    self.bubble = pygame.sprite.Group()


  def run(self):
    self.runn = True
    while self.runn:
        self.clock.tick(60)
        self.watch_for_events()
        self.draw()
        self.events()
        

  def events(self):
    if len(self.bubble)< 100:
        self.bubble.add(Bubble())
        time.sleep(0.2)

 def draw(self):
    self.background.draw(self.screen)
    self.bubble.draw(self.screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

 def watch_for_events(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            self.runn = False
                
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOWS_POS'] = "50, 1100"
pygame.init()
game = Game()
game.run()
pygame.quit()
```

**Thanks for Helping**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Despawn" a bubble by calling [`pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill). `kill` `remove` the Sprite from all Groups. Use the [`MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) and [`pygame.Rect.collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to determine if a bubble is clicked:

```py
class Game(object):
    # [...]
  
    def watch_for_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                self.runn = False

            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                for bubble in self.bubble:
                    if bubble.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        bubble.kill()
```